# JavaScript setting public variable

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question regarding setting 'public' variable in JavaScript. Here is my code:

```
var storeKey;
    firebase.database().ref('stores').orderByChild('storeAddress').equalTo('Blk 167').once('value', function(snapshot) {
      var storeData = snapshot.val();
      if (storeData){
        console.log('exists');
      }else{
        storeKey = firebase.database().ref('stores').push({
          storeName : "store1",
          storeAddress : "Blk 167"
        }).getKey();

        //console.log("STORE " + storeKey);
      }
    });

    console.log("STORE " + storeKey);
```

I am checking if the address exists before adding new record into Firebase. However, if I put the console.log at the last line, I get undefined. It only returns a value if I print it out inside the else statement.

I wanted to separate the storeKey out before I need that data in other places and I don't want my code to be nested inside the else statement. Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function accepts a callback, the `console.log` is called before the callback, that's why its `undefined` One way to "solve" it is using promises. e.g.

```
const deferred = q.defer();
    firebase.database().ref('stores').orderByChild('storeAddress').equalTo('Blk 167').once('value', function(snapshot) {
          var storeData = snapshot.val();
          if (storeData){
            console.log('exists');
          }else{
            storeKey = firebase.database().ref('stores').push({
              storeName : "store1",
              storeAddress : "Blk 167"
            }).getKey();

            deferred.resolve(storeKey);
          }
        });

        deferred.then(console.log)
```

Comment: Hey sorry it was working a while back. But then when I ran the second time, I got this error message 'Promise constructor's argument is not a function'

Comment: @EmmaHannah You can use the `q` library. Example updated. e.g. https://github.com/kriskowal/q#using-deferreds

Comment: But it told me can't find variable Q. How do I define Q? Because I dont see it in the link also

Comment: @EmmaHannah you have to import the library into your project, if is browser based project you will have it on the `window` if its node project you will have to `require` it.

Comment: I solved the promises problem by using the syntax at this site: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: @EmmaHannah yep, thats another way. Native.

Comment: Hey how do I actually access the promise and store it as another variable? For instance, userKey.then(console.log); will print out the value. But then I wanted to access it in the later part, when I print out userKey, it gives me [object Object] instead of the value